# How can I move text to the next line?

Tags: html, css

I am a beginner and doing my first easy challenge, but I got stuck anyway :D
I want to move the text down, to the next line.

In particular, I want to make the  text like this:
[Final result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dl2rc.jpg)

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="/image-qr-code.png" alt="" />
  <p class="main">Improve your front-end skills by building projects</p>
  <p class="second">
    Scan QR Code to visit front-end Mentor and take your coding skills to the next level
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: the easiest way is to move the text to the next line using the <br> tag

Comment: What text, exactly? There is a huge difference between your desired screen shot and the code you have. I recommend picking up a book that teaches basic HTML+CSS to get started.

Comment: @AlanH. That is what I am doing right now if u read my description. Trying to start practising as well and why do you wonder if I have many mistakes? 
Kinda very rude of you!

Comment: I’m not trying to be rude. I am trying to help you out as you are clearly a beginner. Your question lacks a lot of clarity and indicates no familiarity with CSS at all, so I recommend starting with fundamentals. Best wishes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `p` element will wrap automatically when there is a static `width` on the parent. This can also be done by using a static `max-width` on the element you want to constrain. You can also use `margin` to constrain the text relative to its parent. In your case, I used `margin` on `second` and `main` to allow the text to match the image you provided. Here is a simple demonstration:

```css
.container {
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 13px 7px rgb(200 198 198);
  width: 240px;
  max-width: 240px;
  padding: 1em;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin: auto;
}

.contain {
  background-color: blue;
  border-radius: 5px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 1em;
}

img {
 max-width: 100%;
}

.main {
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 1em 2em;
}

.second {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 1em 1em;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="contain">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/150/000/fff&text=QR+CODE" https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72034538/how-can-i-move-text-to-the-next-line# alt="" />
  </div>
  <p class="main">Improve your front-end skills by building projects</p>
  <p class="second">
    Scan QR Code to visit front-end Mentor and take your coding skills to the next level
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: `max-width` is also extremely important and powerful as a tool to cause text-wrapping, assuming that is what OP is hoping to get.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is put them separate divs
This will put the words in another line.

If what you mean was that the text does not overflow, that would include CSS>
Here is some of the code

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: rgb(174, 220, 239);
}

.container {
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  padding-top: 300px;
}

form {
  background-color: white;
  width: 270px;
  padding: 20px;
  padding-top: 90px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <form action="">
    <img src="/image-qr-code.png" alt="" />
    <p class="main">Improve your front-end skills by building projects</p>
    <div class="second">
      <p>
        Scan QR Code to visit front-end Mentor and take your coding skills to the next level
      </p>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Where did the `form` come from? Kind of random.

Comment: I was trying to make the style he wanted from the image he posted